# What's the simplest way to define a transition that switches the locale and returns to the current view-state?

Tags: spring-webflow

We do have the `LocaleChangeInterceptor` configured if that helps.

(Originally posted to http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?123391-Transition-to-set-locale )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not what I was seeking, but it's the only thing I found to do. That is, I created an action method to call from the transition:

```xml
    <transition on="switchLanguage" validate="false">
        <evaluate expression="myAction.switchLanguage"/>
    </transition>
```

And, specifically in this case for an `Action` class that extends [`MultiAction`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.x/api/org/springframework/webflow/action/MultiAction.html):

```java
public Event switchLanguage(RequestContext context)
{
    // get the "other" locale string itself from the current locale's resource bundle
    Locale locale = context.getExternalContext().getLocale();
    MessageSource ms = context.getActiveFlow().getApplicationContext();
    String newLocaleString = ms.getMessage("lang.other", null, locale);

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getNativeRequest();
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getNativeResponse();

    LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(req);
    localeResolver.setLocale(req, res, StringUtils.parseLocaleString(newLocaleString));
    return success();
}
```

Where, in my case, I only have to support two languages, so I define in my two `messages.properties` and `messages_es.properties` files, the property:

```
lang.other=es
```

or

```
lang.other=en
```

For other Action class approaches, return whatever you need to to indicate no failures, to either return to the same state again, or to transition to a new state, as desired.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/views.html#transition-actions

> If the transition action invokes a plain Java method, the invoked method may return a boolean whose value, true or false, indicates whether the transition should take place or be prevented from executing. A method may also return a String where the literal values "success", "yes", or "true" indicate the transition should occur, and any other value means the opposite.

Comment: What is success() here? @dbreaux

Comment: @Aliy ahh, sorry. That's when my Action class extends `AbstractAction`, which has a `success()` method to return a success `Event`. I'll edit the answer to state that.

Comment: Actually this solution did not work in my project, I have no clue how to implement multi language feature in Spring Webflow, because of webflow's redirects, I have been struggling for a week now! I thought your solution would help but i did not understand your code)) @dbreaux

Answer (score 1):

Better would be to use existing components. Here is snippet of Spring WebFlow configured to use "LocaleChangeInterceptor":

```
@Bean
public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping(FlowDefinitionRegistry flowDefinitionRegistry) {
    FlowHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new FlowHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setInterceptors(new Object[] { localeChangeInterceptor() });
    // ... other configuration
    return handlerMapping;
}

/**
 * @category locale_switcher
 */
@Bean
public SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return localeResolver;
}

/**
 * @category locale_switcher
 */
@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
    return localeChangeInterceptor;
}
```

How it works:

```
http://localhost:8080/myflow?execution=e1s1&lang=en
```