# How to handle different locale value in spring 3.0 webflow

Tags: spring-webflow

I want to handle the different locale value, based on that I should display the error messages in jsp pages
how to handle different locale value in spring webflow with jsp ?

Below code snippet is, from one of my java controller file,

```
**msgContext.addMessage(new MessageBuilder().error().source("register")
                              .code("createAccountForm.emailAddress.alreadyexists").build());**
```

And the below is one of my jsp file, where I am displaying the above error message as follows,

```
**.......
<spring:hasBindErrors name="createAccountForm">
<c:forEach var="error" items="${errors.allErrors}">
<div style="font-weight:bold;color:#ff0000;"><c:out value="${error.defaultMessage}"/></div></c:forEach> 
</spring:hasBindErrors>
........**
```

Now, I want to add **2 more property files** for error messages for different locale values.
    In this scenario how can I add the locale value ? [I will get the locale value in the above java file], so that based on the **different locale value**, I should display the error messages in my above jsp file ?

Answer (score 1):

You simply create the appropriately named properties files, e.g. `messages_en.properties` for English, and have something [configured](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/LocaleChangeInterceptor.html) or [coded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504478/whats-the-simplest-way-to-define-a-transition-that-switches-the-locale-and-retu) to set the current Locale.

See [Working with Messages](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/ch05s13.html).